# ios swift cannot dismiss view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am opening new viewcontroller like

```
            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let view_controller1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "incident_view_id") as! IncidentViewController
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            //self.present(registerViewController, animated: true)
             let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: view_controller1)
            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Which works fine,

Now when I press a button I need to close current view and go back previous view, I tired

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

But not works, I tried this too

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But same result.

Comment: If I understand your code, you show a navigation controller with one view and try to pop from this view but you only have one view in your navigation stack.

Comment: I have main viewcontroller, that was initial view controller, from there I am opening an new view controller as above using storyboard id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are presenting your `ViewController` in a wrong way. The following line tells the application to no matter what `ViewControllers` you have opened, just throw it out and assign the `UINavigationController` what you are creating, as the rootViewController. So the reason your code, the `dismiss`, is not working because there are no other `ViewControllers` behind your current one.

```
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController // Wrong
```

This usually goes into the beginning of the applications, where you define with which `UIViewController` you want to start your application. I believe you are calling the first code chunk you posted from a `UIViewController`. So what you need to do instead of creating a new `UINavigationController` and assigning it to the `rootViewController`, you just use the `UIViewController`s navigation controller to push the next `UIViewController`.

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let view_controller1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "incident_view_id") as! IncidentViewController
navigationController?.pushViewController(view_controller1, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check it and report back.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, now the code works fine with `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

Comment: Glad that it helped.